# Finding strings in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have multiple columns with similar data in it, and i have multiple words that i would like to know if they are in one of those columns.
As an example :

```
df = data.frame(ttt1= c("METO","LETO","META","LETA","METO"),
                ttt2=c("LETO","","METO","","LETA"))
df
  ttt1 ttt2
1 METO LETO
2 LETO     
3 META METO
4 LETA     
5 METO LETA
```

I would like, from those columns starting with "ttt" OR containing "ttt", create columns like this way :

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(cl_m = ifelse(ttt1 %in% c("METO", "META") | ttt2 %in% c("METO", "META"), 1, 0),
         cl_l = ifelse(ttt1 %in% c("LETO", "LETA") | ttt2 %in% c("LETO", "LETA"), 1, 0))
df2
  ttt1 ttt2 cl_m cl_l
1 METO LETO    1    1
2 LETO         0    1
3 META METO    1    0
4 LETA         0    1
5 METO LETA    1    1
```

I found some options with some base R https://copyprogramming.com/howto/check-string-in-columns-r-code-example but that doesnt work with the fact that i want to look for multiple words (i tried with the %in% typo), and with the fact that it doesnt only start with my pattern but it can contain it (m0_ttt, ttt_m0, etc..)

It can be a base-R or a dplyr solution it is not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr`, you could `mutate` and use `across(contains("ttt")...)` to test whether the columns contain the strings of interest. Then use `rowSums` to sum up the number of instances. Since the row sums will never be negative in this context, a little hack was to use `sign()` to convert the sums to 1 or 0 instead of a logical test (ie, `ifelse(..)` or `+(... > 0)`):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(cl_m = sign(rowSums(across(contains("ttt"), ~ +(.x %in% c("METO", "META"))))),
         cl_l = sign(rowSums(across(contains("ttt"), ~ +(.x %in% c("LETO", "LETA"))))))
```

Output:

```
#   ttt1 ttt2 cl_m cl_l
# 1 METO LETO    1    1
# 2 LETO         0    1
# 3 META METO    1    0
# 4 LETA         0    1
# 5 METO LETA    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

On each row use `+any`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(cm = +any(pick(contains("ttt")) %in% c("METO", "META")),
         cl = +any(pick(contains("ttt")) %in% c("LETO", "LETA"))) %>%
  ungroup
## # A tibble: 5 × 4
##   ttt1  ttt2      cm    cl
##   <chr> <chr>  <int> <int>
## 1 METO  "LETO"     1     1
## 2 LETO  ""         0     1
## 3 META  "METO"     1     0
## 4 LETA  ""         0     1
## 5 METO  "LETA"     1     1
```

Even shorter is `+if_any`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(cm = +if_any(contains("ttt"), ~ . %in% c("METO", "META")),
         cl = +if_any(contains("ttt"), ~ . %in% c("LETO", "LETA")))
##   ttt1 ttt2 cm cl
## 1 METO LETO  1  1
## 2 LETO       0  1
## 3 META METO  1  0
## 4 LETA       0  1
## 5 METO LETA  1  1
```